# Purpose of tags which only describe how a puzzle is presented

Tags: discussion, tags

There are several tags which do not identify an element relating to the puzzle (or its solution) itself, but rather identify how the puzzle is presented. This is most notable with tags relating to poetry, e.g. [poetry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry), [limerick](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limerick), [haiku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haiku). The [rhyme](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhyme) tag is often used simply as the tag description states, although there are exceptions where the use of rhyme is part of the solution(s), e.g. [these](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/24284/8949) [questions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/18764/8949). The [story](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story) tag is also one I would put into this category.

Only the [rhyme](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhyme) tag has any followers (and only 1 at that), and I am unsure why one would use any of the other tags as filters. So is there some other advantage to using tags which only describe how a puzzle is presented?

Comment: If I were looking for a previous puzzle that was presented in the form of a limerick, it would be very useful to be able to search on the [tag:limerick] tag.  It helps to categorize the post, which seems to me to be the purpose of tags.

Comment: For the record, I sort of feel like the "rhyme" tag is not terribly useful. If a person was trying to find a post where something rhymed, there are approximately eight billion things they would search for (and have more reliable results with) before "rhyme".

Comment: I read your post and decided to see a few limerick puzzles. I knew of limericks, I didn't know they could be puzzles as well. How would I have searched them if the tag didn't exist?

Comment: Sometime this helps me, I am extremely annoyed by rhyming puzzles.